# Jackson Ser/Deser: Proxying an object to/from an id w/ a different key

Tags: java, json, deserialization, jackson

Apologies in advance. This seems like a simple task, but hours later on Google and with guess/check, I still can't figure it out.

I'm writing a Java convenience wrapper library for an API my company provides. One of the classes looks something like this:

```
class View extends Model<View>
{
    List<Column> columns;
    Column primaryColumn;
}
```

However, our API actually wants a `primaryColumnId` integer, not an actual `Column` object. I want to maintain the strongly-typed `getPrimaryColumn()` and `setPrimaryColumn(Column)` in the library to reduce developer error, but I'm having significant difficulty writing some sort of translation between the getter/setter that we need to ser/deser to/from JSON.

I'm using the standard Bean serialization strategy. I'd like to avoid the wholly-custom approach because in reality `View` has dozens of fields. Here's what I've figured out so far.

I *think* (haven't tested yet) that I can handle the **serialization** case simply by creating a custom `JsonSerializer` that looks something like:

```
public static class ColumnIdSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Column>
    {
        @Override
        public void serialize(Column column, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator,
                              SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
            jsonGenerator.writeFieldName("primaryColumnId");
            jsonGenerator.writeNumber(column.id);
        }
    }
```

And then assigning the annotation to the appropriate place:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = Column.ColumnIdSerializer.class)
public Column getPrimaryColumn() { /* ... */ }
```

This allows me to serialize the `id` rather than the whole class, and rename the key from `primaryColumn` to `primaryColumnId`.

Now, we get to **deserialization**. Here I run into three problems.

The first is that in order to successfully deserialize the column from the id, we have to first have the list of columns. This is solvable using `@JsonPropertyOrder` on the class. Great, that's done.

The second is that I need to tell Jackson to look under `primaryColumnId` rather than `primaryColumn` for the value. I don't know how to do this; the `JsonDeserializer` appears to kick in *after* the key has already been found, so it's too late to modify it. `JsonSchema` looks like it might be relevant but I can't find any documentation or internet chatter on how to *use* it.

The third is that from the custom `JsonDeserializer` class I'll have to be able to reference the `View` that's being deserialized in order to ask it for a `Column` in return for my `id` int. There doesn't appear to be a way to do that.

Should I just cave and add a public `getPrimaryColumnId()` and `setPrimaryColumnId(Integer)`, or is there a way to overcome these obstacles?

Comment: What exactly is `Column`? Can you share the class def?

Comment: It's not terribly interesting, just a bunch of fields. The `View` I've given is abbreviated, too. `Column` has a bunch of stuff like `id`, `name`, `flags`, `dataType`, etc. It's currently just sitting as a static inner class in `View`. What exactly would you like to know about it?

Comment: Does it match the bean pattern? When you serialize it, what parts of it do you need to serialize?

Comment: It matches the bean pattern, and when I normally serialize it (eg as part of the `List<Column> columns` field), it works great. The only issue is that the `Column primaryColumn` field shouldn't be serialized as a `Column`, it should be serialized/deserialized as the equivalent of `int primaryColumnId`.

Comment: I see, is there something stopping you from writing a wrapper class and serializing that instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that since Jackson does nasty reflection, it can see through `private` methods. So, the trick ended up simply being along the lines of:

```
private void setPrimaryColumnId(Integer id) {...}

private Integer getPrimaryColumnId() {...}

public void setPrimaryColumn(Column column) {...}

@JsonIgnore
public Column getPrimaryColumn() {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

So I'd propose something like this:

```
class CustomView
{
    private final View parent;
    public CustomView(View view){
        parent = view;
    }

    // Jackson needs a no-arg constructor
    public CustomView(){
        parent = new View();
    }

    // ...
    public List<Columns> getColumns(){ ... }
    public void setColumns(List<Columns> columns){ ... }

    public int getPrimaryColumn(){
        return parent.getPrimaryColumn().getColumnId();
    }
    public void setPrimaryColumn(int column){
        parent.getPrimaryColumn().setColumnId(column);
    }
    //...

    // don't use `get` in the method name here to avoid serialization
    public View rawView(){
        return parent;
    }
}
```

If needed this can be written to extend `View`, but be careful to mask methods where appropriate.

Comment: +1 for seconding one of my ideas. Still really hoping to find a more elegant/Jackson-based solution from someone, but if nothing surfaces I'll go with this. Thanks!